# Is it a good practise to remove a function instead of making it stay there with a deprecated annotation

Tags: java, deprecated, jls

So i had this long argument with some guys and they kept fighting over their self made code conventions.
According to which , they said if there is a method that you while coding the stuff you thought it should be deprecated.You simply remove it,change everywhere it has been used,notify others and let them change their stuff too.

## My counter question

What if java people simply removed the Date class instead of deprecating it and still they would not agree.

## Expectation

Even if i am wrong, i would expect a nice explanation to the fact.
Some additional facts or links would be great.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a place for you to go to settle arguments

Comment: It depends on the circumstances.  In new development you should generally remove nonfunctional code ASAP, though coordinating with your coworkers.  When you have a public API that is used by thousands or millions, however, you have to be a little more careful.

Comment: And there are no "facts" to back this up, one way or the other.  It's a decision based on experience, policy within your group, and common sense.

Comment: If you just deprecate the method, people will simply go on using it. They disregard warnings, anyway---at least that's my experience. Delete the method -> force everyone to adapt -> have better code tomorrow. Of course, we're talking *in-house* code at both ends. Public libraries are a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe might be something for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

If you were making a library used by others, a new version should not **break** existing code. Only after a major revision, say from 3.8.7 to 4.0 you might require the users to recode. Mind that other bug repairs might make a branching, a back porting to a new 3.8.8 becessary.

Mind those others might use still other libraries, that use your library too. So being **backward compatible** means people can upgrade without waiting that a library that uses your library is upgraded.

For a local company's internal library it might be more appealing, to remove the old API, ensuring that everyone in the firm switches to the new code.

There are still some uses for `@Deprecated` locally:

I had once a method with a `long` parameter that in the new version would be `Object`. I did this in a library:

```
/**
 * Please replace the long parameter with the Object ...
 */
@Deprecated
public boolean f(long x) { ... }

public boolean f(Object x) { ... }
```

Here simply deleting the old version would be fatal for all library usages, apart from an ugly `if (x instanceof Long) { return fOld(((Long)x).longValue()); }` in the new function.

So a deprecation might give a javadoc info on what to replace the call with. Generally shown in IDEs as popup window.

Answer (score 1):

From the time being I am with Java, I have just seen a clause about the deprecated things in java from good sources and found it completely valid,

Clause is

---

### *However from 'X' version of java this 'abc' feature is deprecated because of 'xyz' reason,but you may come across some old code in your career,so its a good thing to have knowledge about it*

But its a very rare case that Java people will have to remove something by flagging anything as deprecated.The deprecated flag just says that it should not be used in future.
And its valid too, if issues related to backward compatibility are considered.

**In context with writing some api yourself,you may have your own circumstances.**